# Embed HTML5 video to web - autoplay on desktop and controls on tablet

Tags: ios, html, video

how can I make this video to autoplay without any controls and in loop and then on tablet devices will show with play button (as IOS autoplay wont work anymore). the link to the video embed converter is http://v4e.thewikies.com/ for now i can only have either or.

Comment: this is not what the `embedded` tag is for.

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: embedded is for discussion on embedded software so mostly microcontroller or low-level linux stuff.  *not* embedding X in Y for arbitrary values of X and Y.